# Быстрый поиск по файлам Python

Tags: python

Как сделать быстрый поиск по нескольким базам, весят они больше гигабайта, а некоторые меньше мегабайта.

База в csv и txt

Comment: А что за базы у вас? И что означает "База в csv и txt"?

Comment: На Sphinx смотрели?

Comment: что такое sphinx?

Comment: Система полнотекстового поиска. Но думаю , что данные у вас табличные, и такой вариант не подойдет. Вам нужны индексы. Либо изобретайте их сами, либо экспортируйте данные в SQLite и проиндексируйте требуемые поля. Он кстати умеет работать с csv, но какие возможности предоставляет, я не интересовался. Гигабайт для него не проблема. Прямо сейчас работаю с базой на 14 гигабайт.